# How to manage access and refresh JWTs in HTTP only cookies

Tags: authentication, jwt

Currently, I have this setup: my API sends back JWT access and refresh tokens in the http response body on auth/login. On each request to the API, client will send access token in auth header. If server responds with unauthorized (token expired), then client will call auth/refresh, obtain new tokens and resubmit the request. If refresh token is invalid, then direct user to the login page. I got this setup by following this [tutorial](https://www.elvisduru.com/blog/nestjs-jwt-authentication-refresh-token). The NestJS official docs have a similar approach, except they did not have a refresh token.

Then I realized I did not have a good place to store these tokens on the client side. LocalStorage is no good, but I've read that HTTP only cookies are the way to go. But there seems to be two strategies for this:

1. Store only the refresh token in cookies and have the client deal with the storage of the access token. I'm thinking storing it in React context, and if user refreshes the page, they will just have to call auth/refresh to obtain a new token. Client will send the access token on every request. If it is expired, the server will either respond with unauthorized, and client will have to call auth/refresh manually, or the server can just refresh automatically, send back new tokens, and process the request?
2. Other people recommend storing both access and refresh tokens in cookies. This way, client doesn't have to worry at all about tokens. I'm thinking the server will always first check the access token. If it is expired, check the refresh token. If that is good, replace the tokens in cookies and process the request. This means the auth/refresh route is no longer needed. This also brings up the question of why we even need 2 tokens, because with this strategy, the user is always guaranteed to authenticate so long as the refresh token is valid? Why not just have a long lived access token, and if you need to revoke it, just do so.

I've read about option 2 in several places, but nowhere have I found a good description of how to actually manage the expiration of tokens. Are these valid/common methods of handling JWTs? I realize that auth is much better handled with auth providers and I will probably end up using one on a more serious project where I care more about security, but for now I just want to understand the basic flow of how people handle this on their own.

PS. I'm using React + NextJS on frontend and NestJS on backend in case there are specific recommendations related to that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the part about why you think you don't need two tokens. But definitely go with the cookie-storing route as you might need to access the tokens from the server especially since you are using next.js.

If your token expires you should receive some kind of error from your backend, usually a 401 or 403 error depending on your backend setup. For example, you could use axios and setup an [interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) for every request to check if you receive an auth error from the backend and if you do send a refresh token to get a new access token. If that fails again log-out the user and request a new sign-in or as an alternative you can setup a number of retires before you logout the user

Comment: So this (your 2nd paragraph) is the part that confuses me about having 2 tokens. You say that the backend will respond with 40X if access token is invalid. If so, send a refresh token. But if both tokens are in the cookies, the backend has access to the refresh token on every request. Why not just automatically refresh the token if access token expires instead of sending a 40X, which is like saying, "Hey you're not authorized. Send me that refresh token that you already sent me."

Comment: Oh actually, I get why we have 2 tokens now. You can't have a long-lived AT because that cannot be revoked. This is the reason ATs have short lives; they don't need to be revoked because they just expire. The RT on the other hand provides a mechanism to refresh the AT. If you revoke the RT (delete the hashed RT entry in the database), then the user will have access only until the AT expires and will have no way of accessing resources after that.

Comment: I still don't understand why the client still has to call /refresh manually though? Why not have server just refresh for you?

Comment: Idk how your architecture is set up but the basic jist of it is this. You require a resource > an AT with the request for that resource > server checks sends ok or error > if the error you send RT to a different endpoint > receive new AT or error > if error log-out if ok repeat with new AT step one. The remote server cant store your RT and AT. Also doesn't have access to your tokens upon you sending a request unless you send both which makes no sense from a security standpoint. The reason I told you to use cookies is that you can use them with server-side rendering, unlike local storage.

Comment: This is basically what I’m already doing. But if I switch to using HTTP only cookies, my understanding is that those are inaccessible from javascript, and thus the client would not be able to pick and choose tokens to send to the server. They are just automatically sent on every request. Or are you suggesting to use regular cookies (not HTTP only cookies)? Because my understanding is that those are not secure because they are accessibly from JavaScript.

Comment: Also, about the server storing tokens. I currently have the server storing a hash of the RT. When auth/refresh endpoint is called, it verifies the RT from client against the hashed RT in the database. When client calls auth/logout, the hashed RT is cleared from DB and so user can no longer refresh and must re login.